# Apache user does not have access to view files

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd

I am working on fixing an issue that one of our webservers is having. There is a simlink to a directory to a mount point on our network storage. The apache user used to be able to see these files but now the apache user cannot see the files and puts the following error in the apache error log. `Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible`

When I attempt to su as the apache user and go to the location of the data I am trying to access I get a `Permission denied` error. As the root user when I go to the directory and show the permissions, this is what shows, `drwxr-s--- randomuser randomgroup` The apache user is part of the random user's group `uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache),106(randomuser)`

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

If you need more information please let me know and I will provide it.

I have been trying to get this fixed for about a week now. Anything anyone can offer would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

The paths and uid/gid make me think this is a rhel/CentOS/Fedora system.  If so, you need to set the `httpd_use_nfs` SELinux Boolean with semanage:

```
setsebool -P httpd_use_nfs=on
```

Use `httpd_use_cifs` if it is a SMB share and not NFS, you don’t say in your post.